# Add additional attributes to an existing document elasticsearch with PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have to add an additional attribute to elastic search index which has n documents without using id(we don't know the id of document) in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$params = ['index' => 'my_index','id'    => 'my_id','body'  => ['doc' => ['new_field' => 'abc']]];
$response = $client->update($params);